# «Звучанье», как поэтическое, можно употребить слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, поэзия

«Звучанье», как поэтическое, можно употребить слово? С мягким знаком...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы и не употребить? Нормальное слово ([звучанье](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5)), используемое и в поэзии, и в прозе.

*Нержин, хотя и математик, но не чужд был языкознанию, и с тех пор, как **звучанье** русской речи стало материалом работы Марфинского научно-исследовательского института, Нержина всё время спаривали с единственным здесь филологом Рубиным.* [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

*В пятый номер («Сибирских огней») пошла подборка из таких Ваших стихотворений: «Неисчислима звездная семья», «**Звучанье** песен старых ― звон капели»...* [М. А. Небогатов. Дневниковые записи разных лет (1981)]

*Так, верно, дирижеру,

Что смотрит партитуру,

Слышны **звучанье** хора,

Напев фиоритуры.* [Семен Лунгин. Виденное наяву (1989-1996)]

*Перечитывал Тициана Табидзе в переводе Бориса Пастернака и выделил чеканную строку ― «Единой Отчизны **звучанье**»*. [Павел Сиркес. Труба исхода (1990-1999)]

*Каждая крыша во время дождя издавала свое, неповторимое **звучанье***. [Игорь Муханов. Виват, Поэзия // «Дальний Восток», 2019]